# initializing a local variable to data-segment string

Tags: c, string, initialization

In **c**, let us say I have the following code:

```
int func(){
 char* s = "bla";
}
```

I am not sure as to what this is compiled.
Since `s` isn't static, it doesn't survive after `func()` ends so it seems that the pointer to "bla" is lost.
On the other hand, the program should still know the address to "bla" so the next time `func()` is called, `s` will get the same address.

I wonder if the above code is ok or if I must declare `s` as static?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how you are going to use this local pointer. Nevertheless the address of the string literal will be the same. It does not depend on how many times the function will be called. This string literal has static storage duration. So the pointer will be initialized with the same address each time when the function gets the control. There is no need to declare the pointer itself as static unless you change its initial value and want that it would be stored in the pointer between function's calls.

Comment: So , from what I understand from your answer is that the program does remember the address of "bla", it is probably hardcoded in the text segment in the instruction that put this address into s. Right?

Comment: @user1580025 String literals have static storage duration. Their addresses are not changed during the program execution. The local pointer defined in your function will be initialized with the same address of the string literal each time the function gets the control.